# Where is the '-sval' parameter coming from when using Visual Studio 2019 to build my wix4 installer?

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2019, heatwave

I have an old wix 3 installer that I have converted to wix 4 using the heatwave wix4 for VS2019 package.

When I try to build it the wix build command that VS generates has the command line option '-sval' on it which results in the error:

> error WIX0118: Additional argument '-sval' was unexpected

When I execute the wix build command directly from a terminal window after removing the offending argument the build runs.

I think -sval was a parameter used by the old wix linker tool.
Does anybody know of a way to remove this argument.

Comment: Share your .wixproj. That'll have the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rob!

The problerm was a linker option that was in my wixproj file:

```
<LinkerAdditionalOptions>-sval</LinkerAdditionalOptions>
```